# Fetch records in SQLAlchemy ORM using back-populate

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have two classes representing tables A and B as shown below

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Class A(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column("user_id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column("user_name", String)
    products = relationship("B", back_populates = "users")

Class B(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column("prod_id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column("user_name", String)
    users = realtionship("A", back_populates = "products")
```

I want to access all the users who bought a product or vice-versa using the properties products/users. Any ideas how can this be done without using session?

Comment: What? What have you tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: @univerio`user_prods = A.products(filter(user_name="userA"))` - This one fails as filter doesn't take keyword arguments.

Comment: That's not even the correct syntax for normal relationships, let alone `back_populates`. Try `session.query(A).filter(A.name == "userA").one().products`?

Comment: @univerio : That was an example of what I wanted to do. I forgot to mention in the question that I wanted to achieve this without using session if possible. I knew how to do it using session.

Comment: Why don't you want to do it with session? session is the heart of the ORM. If you're not using the session, you're not using the ORM at all. Do you mean you want to construct a query with SQLAlchemy Core? It's really unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: @univerio : Ok. So I realized that session will be required. I needed one clarification though. What is the use of `.one()`? Is it assuming that there would be multiple users with same name and that `session.query(A).filter(A.name == "userA")` would return multiple records?

Comment: No. `session.query()` returns a `Query`. `Query.filter()` *generatively adds filtering criteria to the `Query`*. If you iterative through a `Query` you'll get a list of results.  `Query.one()` asserts that the query returns one and exactly one row, and return the object constructed from the row alone, instead of in a list. Similarly, you can also do `Query.scalar()` or `Query.first()`. They both do similar but subtly different things. You can find details in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one).